# Typescript - How to get keys behind specific values from an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-utility

I have a super simple use-case. I want have a function `pluckOnlyStringValues` on which I pass an object `obj` and a `key` and I want to ensure that I can pass only such keys whose values are `string`. In such a way that `pluckOnlyStringValues` always returns `string`.

For the goal I'm trying implementing a type helper `PickKeysByValue`, but it does not seem to work...

```
type PickKeysByValue<T extends object, ValueTypes> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends ValueTypes ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

// Working
type GetKeysWithStringValues = PickKeysByValue<
  { a: string; b?: string; c: number | undefined; d: () => 4 },
  string
>;
// Working
type GetStringValues = { a: string; b?: string; c: number | undefined; d: () => 4 }[GetKeysWithStringValues]

// Not working
const pluckOnlyStringValues = <O extends { a: string }>(
  obj: O,
  key: PickKeysByValue<O, string>,
): string => {
  return obj[key];
};
```

Comment: why are you constraining `O` to `{ a: string }`? You should replace it with `Record<string, any>` or `Record<string, any> & { a: string }` to indicate that `obj` can be indexed with a `string`.

Comment: @TobiasS. this was the issue indeed. Good catch! Would you want to answer officially in order to mark this as accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the constraint of `O` to `Record<string, any>`, TypeScript will know that `O` is indexable with a `string`.

```
const pluckOnlyStringValues = <O extends Record<string, any>>(
  obj: O,
  key: PickKeysByValue<O, string>,
): string => {
  return obj[key];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description,..

You could do this with a helper type, `StringKeys`, this would then just return Keys that are string types.

```
const test = {
  aNumber: 12,
  aString: 'ABC'
};

type StringKeys<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never
}[keyof T];

function pluckString<T extends object>(obj:T, key:StringKeys<T>) {
  return obj[key];
}

pluckString(test, 'aString')  //ok
pluckString(test, 'aNumber'); //error
```

[Playground with Return](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YG8BQMYEMByArgLYBG8ATgFwwCMATADRa4DKU5AlmAObUDkAQQBCAYT4YAvgG4MGKAE8ADvBhtOPANLx5EADwAVGPAAeCMABMIMECQBW8YFAB8KdMwDaGmFxgBrbSAAZjD6ALrU%20p6hRqbwFlbQ6twwAPwwXtRg8ABuFJLu-vJBIaEyGIEEYI4c4DCKADYEwL5qXNwGMWaW1nYOzgAUNraU%20gx%202pStmtp6%20k4AlG7Y5PBQBORgPbYF2qWSsg1NLext-QjQY3w4U9x8izAA9A8gvhiHzTdniFCX%20MRk5DuUkeDwo5BA5FkQA)

Comment: this is not working when we try to access `obj[key]` within the function. ```function pluckString<T extends object>(obj:T, key:StringKeys<T>): string {
  return obj[key]
}```

Comment: @KamenKanev Works for me..  Updated Playground with it on.

Comment: Setting an explicit return type to the function reviels the problem. I've updated the playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YG8BQMYEMByArgLYBG8ATgFwwCMATADRa4DKU5AlmAObUDkAQQBCAYT4YAvgG4MGKAE8ADvBhtOPANLx5EADwAVGPAAeCMABMIMECQBW8YFAB8KdMwDaGmFxgBrbSAAZjD6ALrU+p6hRqbwFlbQ6twwAPwwXtRg8ABuFJLu-vJBIaEyGIEEYI4c4DCKADYEwL5qXNwGMWaW1nYOzgAUNraU+gx+2pStmtp6+k4AlNSJbW7Y5PBQBORgPbYF2qWSsg1NLext-QjQY3w4U9x889gA9M8gvhgnzfeXiFA3+GIZHIjykMFeFHIIHIsiAA

Comment: @KamenKanev  Why are you setting an explicit return?, the implied type is `string`.  If you over type Typescript your really using it wrong.   Try and keep as much as you can implicit, and Typescript works with you, rather than against.

Comment: @KamenKanev  This might be a useful video -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RmGHnYUqQ4k&t=35s

Comment: I'm using this just to prove the point that the inference is not right. Setting explicit `string` type proves the point. You can check the @Tobias comment below and see that using `extends React<string, any>` over `extends {}` solves the problem.

Comment: `I'm using this just to prove the point that the inference is not right.`  It's totally the opposite, the inference is totally correct, it's a `string`,  what your doing is now saying `T <> string` and that of course is wrong.  IOW, your jumping out of the generic type, and why would you want to do that since the it's returning the correct type?.  Keeping Generic types generic for as long as possible is really beneficial to Typescript in the long run.  But if you believe my answer is not useful, I'll delete it, and you can keep over typing if that's your thing..